# Let the Application Server Handle the DB Connection Pooling

Tags: java, hibernate, database-connection, connection-pooling

Im using JNDI for datasource defined in our application server(websphere) and it is configured to manage the db connection pool. I have a service deployed on that server which also defines db connection pooling as per the cofiguration below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" version="1.0">
    <persistence-unit name="test">
        <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.c3p0.min_size" value="1"/>
            <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_size" value="10"/>

            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>
            <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true"/>
            <property name="hibernate.ejb.autodetection" value="hbm"/>
            <property name="hibernate.use_sql_comments" value="true"/>
        </properties>        
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Now, my goal is to completely remove the db connection pooling management on the service and let the application service handle it. If I remove the two c3p0 entries, does that mean no db connection pooling is happening inside the service and all are managed by the application server?

Im new to this kind of thing, and inputs or reference is highly appreciated. Thanks

**[UPDATE1]**

From [C3P0ConnectionProvider](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/4.0/javadocs/org/hibernate/service/jdbc/connections/internal/C3P0ConnectionProvider.html) "Hibernate will use this by default if the hibernate.c3p0.* properties are set."

Based on the above xml, I already removed the default pooling. Now if I did not define any pooling provider on the service then I essentially removed the pooling on the service right? I feel this is a dumb question now but please confirm if this is correct. Thanks :)

Comment: What do you mean by "let the server handle the connection pooling"?

Comment: I mean let the JNDI set in server to manage the connection pool

Comment: and what is the target database?! I hope it is not M$-SQL. and what do you mean by `Server`? you mean application server(run time) or database server?! letting the db server manages the pooling is not very optimized way, because you have just missed the runtime management and pooling too, and about the app server I don't know because of vary impl of pooling, but generally app server manages the pool and JNDI guys.

Comment: @user2511414 Unfortunately MS-SQL. Application Server... our organization is using Websphere and there they defined JNDI to handle handle database connection pooling. The service deployed in websphere server also has its own db connection pooling defined. My goal is to completely remove the service db connection pooling and let the application server handle it.